# Experinacing No Write Access with PHP Pages that have No Extension

Tags: php, apache, fwrite

I have my own caching system in place. All pages are writing cached files, except on two pages.

Strangely it boils down that these two files have no php extensions and I am using `ForceType application/x-httpd-ea-php74` under Apache.

These two pages are working as PHP pages, draw SQL queries, and seem to be working perfectly fine. The only issue I am encountering is they do not have write access, using both `fwrite` or `file_put_contents`.

Anyone heard of this? Is it a security road block with PHP or cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Moving ForceType application/x-httpd-ea-php74 to htaccess worked. Had it originally under the virtual host. This has to be a new security change under Apache or cPanel.